# Tkinter Unhandled Exception 1% is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first foray into Tkinter as I have been programming in ArcGIS. I just downloaded Tkinter to do some python programming. I did the regular install and when I open the application, anytime I try to start a project or go to the code window, I keep getting an unhandled exception:

"Unhandled Exception 1% is not a valid win32 application"

I've looked around the net, but I don't see any discussion boards addressing this issue. I am running python v2.6 through ArcGIS. I regularly program in idle. I don't know if the software is conflicting with each other.

I am also running windows 7, 64 bit. I tried the install in both program files folders and get the same error.

has anyone experienced this?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the bit-ness of the tkinter library you have installed - something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/python-tkinter-on-windows).