# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application in importing tkinter- python3.4.1

Tags: windows, tkinter, python-3.4

I have windows 7 64 bit and I am using python 3.4.1 for 64bit but still I am getting import error. I have searched and found tkinter folder in my python34/Lib/ directory but still I cannot get tkinter working. I am a newbie in python so any idea how can i get around with this issue?

[ImportError DLL load failed importing _tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/python-tkinter-on-windows/26259064#26259064)

Also this link provides some views on this issue but its related to 32 bit python on 64 bit windows and mine is 64 bit

Comment: How did you install python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. I re-installed python once but that did not worked but when I again re-installed python on my system and then this issue was resolved but I still could not figure out what was wrong earlier