# Using easygui in Visual Studio Python Tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ptvs, easygui

I'm trying to import the easygui module into Visual Studio Python Tools, but thus far I have been unable to get it to work.  Whenever I run anything involving importing easygui I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
2, in exec_code
exec(code_obj, global_variables)
File "C:\Users\dan\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MoreGuiTests\MoreGuiT
ests\MoreGuiTests.py", line 1, in <module>
from easygui import *
File "C:\Users\dan\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MoreGuiTests\MoreGuiT
ests\easygui.py", line 155, in <module>
from Tkinter import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
import FixTk
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've tried several downloads of easygui, both version .96 and .97, with one of the .96 versions having a setup.py.  The other ones just have a easygui.py file and a **init**.py file.  I've tried installing them through command prompt and importing them Visual Studio, however I haven't been able to get anything to work.  I've also tried putting copies of the easygui.py and **init**.py into the project folder, however I would still get the same errors.  I've been using Python 2.7.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
The problem was due to an difference in types between Python and _tkinter (x32, x64).  Reinstalling Python fixed this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for the difficulty.  A previous question has the same symptoms (not necessarily the same fix): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/python-tkinter-on-windows

Comment: This appears to be an issue with your Python install.  easygui uses Tkinter underneath.  Please take a look at the previous question referenced in my previous comment.  There are other resources if you Google the last six lines of your error message.