# python, out of nowhere a tkinter error? DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, tkinter

I've been using this script weekly and when I tried to use it today it suddenly gave me the following error:

```
E:\Bots\---NameChecker>python ---NameChecker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---NameChecker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Tkinter import Tk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

This is not the only one however, before this one I had an error about pycrypto, which went away when I updated it, after installing the c++ compiler from the MS website.

Anyone has an idea on what to do here? My coder is away for the next couple of days and I really really need this script to work.

ps. sensitive information replaced with " --- "

Comment: It looks like your Tkinter installation has gotten messed up. Is that machine 64 bit or 32 bit? Does the command `python -m Tkinter` print the same error message? You _may_ be able to un-install Tkinter & re-install it, using the package found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), but you might need to un-install & re-install Python itself, as mentioned in the answers to [ImportError DLL load failed importing _tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8724729/4014959).