# cx_Freeze Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I wrote a basic program to keep track of customer names, vehicles, mileage, and date, and it also has an option for the user to choose to see a company logo that I drew using the turtle module. Then I used cx_freeze to freeze it as an executable, and everything froze and a build file with all the necessary files and folders and an executable was created, but when I run the .exe file I can't choose my option to view the company logo. I continue to get this error when running it in CMD:

```
C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\PythonPrograms\CX\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6>OilChangeEx.exe
At Holden's Oil Change we use our custom built Python program to keep track of customer records and to display our company logo!!
Select and option from the menu!
1   Current Customers
2   New Customers
3   Company Logo
4   Quit
Select an option: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "OilChangeEx.py", line 282, in <module>
  File "OilChangeEx.py", line 56, in main
  File "OilChangeEx.py", line 77, in commandChoice
  File "OilChangeEx.py", line 176, in Turt
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The top part of the error is the actual running of my code and you can see the 4 options; all of these work other than #3.

I have checked in the tkinter documentation and the cx_Freeze documentation and cannot find anything that I am doing wrong. Here is my setup.py file that I am using to build my executable:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["turtle","_tkinter"]}

setup(name='OilChange',
      version='0.1',
      description='OilChangeRecords',
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable('OilChangeEx.py')])
```

The tkinter module in the "includes" for my build_exe, I have tried to remove and spell it just tkinter, I have tried to put both tkinter and turtle, and each individual module in "packages" instead of "includes". I have tried every option that relates to my situation in the cx_Freeze documentation with no luck.

I found another question that closely relates to mine: [import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568915/import-tkinter-if-this-fails-your-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk/44350264?noredirect=1#comment75702900_44350264)  There are no answers to this question and mine somewhat differs.

I am running Windows 10 OS and Python 3.6.1
Also the script does work when ran from the Python IDLE

Answer (score 0):

for the icon what you will need to do is in your setup.py, under the os.environ part set base equal to none(base=None) and then in the executables variable, right after you put OilExchange.py you need to put a comma, say base equals base(base=base), put another comma, write icon and set it equal to your icon directory. Here is my example `executables = [Executable("texteditor.py", base=base, icon="books_logo.ico")]`

Answer (score -1):

here is a more fuller version for clarification

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
#build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
setup(
    name = "VBtEditor",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter", "os", "cx_Freeze"], "include_files": ["books_logo.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Professional text editor part of the VIRTUAL BUREAU",
    executables = [Executable("texteditor.py", base=base,    icon="books_logo.ico")]
```

Comment: you should add this to your original answer, not post a new one