# Python modules do not load. - PyCrypto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, pycrypto

I've written an encryption script with PyCrypto in Python 2.7. However, when trying to convert to an executable file, Crypto does not load and the program shuts down immediately. I've tried PY2EXE, Pyinstaller, and CX_Freeze. i want to know how to make this work. Can anyone tell me how my script.py file should look for Py2exe and Pyinstaller? Thanks. My script:

```
import shutil
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
import os



def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    print("Your key for decryption is: ", key)
    message = pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)


def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
    with open(file_name + '.enc', 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
    with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

key = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'

filename = askopenfilename()

file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

dec = "_dec"

newfile = file_name + dec

copied = ''.join((newfile, file_extension))

shutil.copy(filename, copied )

encrypt_file(filename, key)

master = Tk()

w = Message(master, text="Encrypted!", width = 100)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Its not your main script that is breaking it. The error is probably arising from your `setup.py` script

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568915/import-tkinter-if-this-fails-your-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk/44556851#44556851) out