# create python script to exe

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to use in `cv_freeze` library for create my python script to exe GUI application. my application using `tkinter` only, but when I try to build the exe file: I get an `TCL_LIBRARY` error. why is that? this is my setup code:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("tkinterVid28.py", base=base, icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["easygui","matplotlib"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
    executables = executables
    )
```

and this is myGUI python code:

```
import tkinter
top = tkinter.Tk()
# Code to add widgets will go here...
top.mainloop()
```

I am using in python 3.6,
thanks for helping or not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this before in the first 2 lines of your cx_Freeze setup.py code.

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6'
```

Replace the paths to your correct python paths. If your python path is `C:\Python36-19` then you would want to do

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python36-19\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python36-19\tcl\tk8.6'
```

If you need help finding your Python path let me know. In windows (and I think linux), you can run `where python` and you want to use the path you get up to the PythonXX-XX folder then do `\tcl\tcl8.6` and `\tcl\tk8.6`

Comment: it now build the exe file. but i get this error when i open the exe file: http://i.imgur.com/v2YMpBN.png

Comment: @odri Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568915/import-tkinter-if-this-fails-your-python-may-not-be-configured-for-tk

Comment: thanks bro it now work. lot of thanks!!!

Comment: @odri Great! If you dont mind could you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: yes of curse i now learn how to do that