# How do I get tkinter to work with Blender v2.90?

Tags: python, tkinter, blender

I'm trying to get a Blender python script that uses tkinter to function. It is supposed to open a 3d face object to allow a user to alter the nose for rhinoplasty surgery. However, it relies heavily on tkinter's ability to provide the GUI in order to allow the user to choose the necessary files; and the code won't run past the import statement for it.

Here's the code:

```py
import bpy
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
activate = 0


#select original data points xlsx file
def selectDataPointsFile():
    global dataPointsFile_path
    global activate
    dataPointsFile_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    activate += 1
    
    if (activate == 3):
        addPointsAndFaceButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL

    newDataPointsButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL


#select new data points xlsx file
def selectNewDataPointsFile():
    global newDataPointsFile_path
    global activate
    newDataPointsFile_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.xlsx")])
    activate += 1
    
    if (activate == 3):
        addPointsAndFaceButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    
    faceObjectButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL


#select patient face obj file
def selectFaceObjectFile():
    global faceObjectFile_path
    global activate
    faceObjectFile_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Object files", "*.obj")])
    activate += 1
    print("Data POint Button")
    if (activate == 3):
        meshFileExportButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    
    
    
    
    
#select patient face obj file
def meshFile():
    global meshFile_path
    global activate
    
    meshFile_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    addPointsAndFaceButton['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    
    
    
#add the face with new and old points    
def facePointsAdd():
    r = 1
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(dataPointsFile_path)
    wsheet = wb_obj.active

    wb_objNew = openpyxl.load_workbook(newDataPointsFile_path)
    wsheetNew = wb_objNew.active



    #swap y and z invert old z
    #old nose points
    noseLoop = []
    namez = []
    for i in range(1, 49):
        nosePoint = (wsheet["B"+str(i)].value, -wsheet["D"+str(i)].value, wsheet["C"+str(i)].value)
        noseLoop.append(nosePoint)
        namez.append(wsheet["A"+str(i)].value)
        
        
    #new nose points    
    noseLoopNew = []
    namezNew = []
    for i in range(1, 49):
        nosePointNew = (wsheetNew["B"+str(i)].value, -wsheetNew["D"+str(i)].value, wsheetNew["C"+str(i)].value)
        noseLoopNew.append(nosePointNew)
        namezNew.append(wsheetNew["A"+str(i)].value)
   

    #list of colored points so old and new points matchup
    colorList = []
    colorList.append((0., 0., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 0., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((1., 0., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((20., 30., 60.,0.))
    colorList.append((1., 1., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 0., 1.,0.))
    colorList.append((1., 0., 1.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 1., 1.,0.))
    colorList.append((1., 1., 1.,0.))
    colorList.append((50., 1., 30.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 1., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40., 100., 0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 50., 2.,0.))
    colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
    colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
    colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))
    colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
    colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
    colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))
    colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
    colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
    colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
    colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
    colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
    colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
    colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))




    def makeMat(num):

        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = namez[i])
        mat.diffuse_color = colorList[i]
        mat.specular_color = (1., 1., 1.)
        return mat

  
    
    imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=faceObjectFile_path)


    for i in range(0, 47):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius= r, location=noseLoop[i])
        sphere = bpy.context.object
        sphere.name = namez[i]
        mesh = sphere.data
        mat = makeMat(i)
        mesh.materials.append(mat)
        
        
        
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size= r, location=noseLoopNew[i])
        cube = bpy.context.object
        cube.name = (namezNew[i] + ' New')
        mesh = cube.data
        mat = makeMat(i)
        mesh.materials.append(mat)



    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')


    activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
    
    


    
    for i in range(0, 47):
        bpy.data.objects[namez[i]].select_set(True) # Blender 2.8x

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = activeObj
    bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='VERTEX')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
    
    
    
    #insert mesh 1 (old nose mesh)
    # make mesh
    vertices = noseLoopNew
    edges = []
    faces = [[14,24,23],[14,24,22],[24,18,23],[24,17,22],[24,18,29],[24,29,17],[18,23,41],[17,22,40],[18,41,29],[29,17,40],[29,41,39],[29,40,39],[1,5,23],[5,41,23],[41,39,28],[39,40,28],[5,41,3],[3,41,7],[7,41,28],[28,40,6],[6,40,2],[22,2,4],[40,22,2],[22,4,0],[3,7,35],[7,35,28],[35,34,28],[28,34,6],[6,34,2],[34,2,26],[2,4,26],[4,31,26],[4,0,31],[32,1,5],[32,5,27],[5,27,3],[32,36,27],[3,27,35],[35,36,27],[34,35,36],[36,34,26],[36,26,31]]
    newNoseMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('newNoseMesh')
    newNoseMesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
    newNoseMesh.update()
    # make object from mesh
    newNoseMesh_object = bpy.data.objects.new('newNoseMesh_object', newNoseMesh)
    
    # create a collection
    mesh_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('mesh_collection')
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(mesh_collection)
    
    # add object to scene collection
    mesh_collection.objects.link(newNoseMesh_object)

    bpy.object = newNoseMesh
    newMeshMat = bpy.data.materials.new('New Mesh Mat')
    newMeshMat.use_nodes=True
    nodes = newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes
        

    newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.8, 0, 0.704733,1)
    newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1


    

    newNoseMesh_object.active_material = newMeshMat

    newNoseMesh_object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
    
    
    
    
    #insert mesh 2
    vertices = noseLoop
    edges = []
    faces = [[14,24,23],[14,24,22],[24,18,23],[24,17,22],[24,18,29],[24,29,17],[18,23,41],[17,22,40],[18,41,29],[29,17,40],[29,41,39],[29,40,39],[1,5,23],[5,41,23],[41,39,28],[39,40,28],[5,41,3],[3,41,7],[7,41,28],[28,40,6],[6,40,2],[22,2,4],[40,22,2],[22,4,0],[3,7,35],[7,35,28],[35,34,28],[28,34,6],[6,34,2],[34,2,26],[2,4,26],[4,31,26],[4,0,31],[32,1,5],[32,5,27],[5,27,3],[32,36,27],[3,27,35],[35,36,27],[34,35,36],[36,34,26],[36,26,31]]
    oldNoseMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('oldNoseMesh')
    oldNoseMesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
    oldNoseMesh.update()
    # make object from mesh
    oldNoseMesh_object = bpy.data.objects.new('oldNoseMesh_object', oldNoseMesh)

    # add object to scene collection
    mesh_collection.objects.link(oldNoseMesh_object)

    bpy.object = oldNoseMesh
    meshMat = bpy.data.materials.new('Mesh Mat')
    meshMat.use_nodes=True
    nodes = meshMat.node_tree.nodes
        

    meshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.00205669, 0.8, 0.0157096, 1)
    meshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1 #.4


    

    oldNoseMesh_object.active_material = meshMat

    oldNoseMesh_object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
    
    
    
    
    #change opcacity of face
    activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
    bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 0
    bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
    bpy.context.object.active_material.use_backface_culling = False
    

    #export face
    
    
    exportFileName = activeObj.name
    if "." in activeObj.name:
        print("Yes")
        exportFileName = exportFileName[:-4]
    
    #print(exportFileName)
    #export obj to face to (patientName)MeshNose.obj
    target_file = os.path.join(meshFile_path, exportFileName + ('MeshNose.obj'))

    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_file)
    
    #delete meshes
    bpy.data.objects['newNoseMesh_object'].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    bpy.data.objects['oldNoseMesh_object'].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    # solidify face
    activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
    bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
    
    bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1
    bpy.context.object.active_material.use_backface_culling = False
    
    
    
    
   
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
    

    #closes little window
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()

dataPointsButton = Button(root, text="Select Old Nose Data Point File For Patient(.xlsx)", command=selectDataPointsFile)
newDataPointsButton = Button(root, text="Select New Nose Data Point File For Patient(.xlsx)", command=selectNewDataPointsFile, state=tk.DISABLED)
faceObjectButton = Button(root, text="Select 3d Model Patient Face (.obj)", command=selectFaceObjectFile, state=tk.DISABLED)
meshFileExportButton = Button(root, text="Select the Folder You Want to Export meshFile in", command=meshFile, state=tk.DISABLED)
addPointsAndFaceButton = Button(root, text="Add The Patient's Face with Points", command=facePointsAdd, state=tk.DISABLED)
dataPointsButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
newDataPointsButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
faceObjectButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
meshFileExportButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
addPointsAndFaceButton.grid(row = 4, column = 0)


root.mainloop()

print(dataPointsFile_path)
print(faceObjectFile_path)








r = 1
wb_objTest = openpyxl.load_workbook(dataPointsFile_path)
wsheetTest = wb_objTest.active

wb_objNew = openpyxl.load_workbook(newDataPointsFile_path)
wsheetNew = wb_objNew.active
```

And here's the error it outputs:
[image: console error]

I'm wondering if the issue may be that I have improperly installed tkinter into the Blender ./Scripts/modules folder...

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError DLL load failed importing \_tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729/importerror-dll-load-failed-importing-tkinter)

Comment: @RandomDavis It does not, reinstalling 64-bit nor 32-bit python did not solve this issue. Even when changing the python version that Blender uses in its own file structure.

Comment: Blender allows you to create panels, buttons, file dialogs, etc. using its own gui, so there's really no need to use tkinter. Just use Blender. For more detailed information on Blender scripting, I suggest taking a look at [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Thank you, I'll check it out. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to rewrite this program, but I think I might have to.

Comment: @godpleasehelp: I hope it won't be that much harder (I've never scripted guis in Blender myself). But as a bonus, using the Blender gui tools will make it look native to Blender. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten the code using Blender's built-in GUI instead of tkinter.

Here's that code:

```py
import bpy
import openpyxl
import os

global file_path

file_path = 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\Documents\\DigitizedRhinoplasty\\DigitizedRhinoplasty-main'
 
class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    dataPointsFile_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="dataPointsFile_path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='FILE_PATH')
        
    newDataPointsFile_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="newDataPointsFile_path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='FILE_PATH')
        
    faceObjectFile_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="faceObjectFile_path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='FILE_PATH')
    
    meshFile_path : bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="meshFile_path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='DIR_PATH')
 
 
class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"
 
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        layout.prop(mytool, "dataPointsFile_path")
        layout.prop(mytool, "newDataPointsFile_path")
        layout.prop(mytool, "faceObjectFile_path")
        layout.prop(mytool, "meshFile_path")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
        row.operator("addonname.myop2_operator")
        row.operator("addonname.myop3_operator")
        row.operator("addonname.myop4_operator")
        row.operator("addonname.myop5_operator")
 
 
class ADDONNAME_OT_dataPointsFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "data points file"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):   
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        global dataPointsFile_path
        dataPointsFile_path = file_path + mytool.dataPointsFile_path[1:]
        print(dataPointsFile_path)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class ADDONNAME_OT_newDataPointsFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "new data points file"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop2_operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):   
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        global newDataPointsFile_path
        newDataPointsFile_path = file_path + mytool.newDataPointsFile_path[1:]
        print(newDataPointsFile_path)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class ADDONNAME_OT_faceObjectFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "face object file"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop3_operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):   
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        global faceObjectFile_path
        faceObjectFile_path = file_path + mytool.faceObjectFile_path[1:]
        print(faceObjectFile_path)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class ADDONNAME_OT_meshFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "mesh folder"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop4_operator" 
    
    def execute(self, context):   
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        global meshFile_path
        meshFile_path = file_path + mytool.meshFile_path[1:]
        print(meshFile_path)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
 
class ADDONNAME_OT_addPointsAndFace(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "add points"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop5_operator" 
    
    def execute(self, context):   
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        r = 1
        wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(dataPointsFile_path)
        wsheet = wb_obj.active

        wb_objNew = openpyxl.load_workbook(newDataPointsFile_path)
        wsheetNew = wb_objNew.active

        #swap y and z invert old z
        #old nose points
        noseLoop = []
        namez = []
        for i in range(1, 49):
            nosePoint = (wsheet["B"+str(i)].value, -wsheet["D"+str(i)].value, wsheet["C"+str(i)].value)
            noseLoop.append(nosePoint)
            namez.append(wsheet["A"+str(i)].value)
            
            
        #new nose points    
        noseLoopNew = []
        namezNew = []
        for i in range(1, 49):
            nosePointNew = (wsheetNew["B"+str(i)].value, -wsheetNew["D"+str(i)].value, wsheetNew["C"+str(i)].value)
            noseLoopNew.append(nosePointNew)
            namezNew.append(wsheetNew["A"+str(i)].value)
       

        #list of colored points so old and new points matchup
        colorList = []
        colorList.append((0., 0., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 0., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((1., 0., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((20., 30., 60.,0.))
        colorList.append((1., 1., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 0., 1.,0.))
        colorList.append((1., 0., 1.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 1., 1.,0.))
        colorList.append((1., 1., 1.,0.))
        colorList.append((50., 1., 30.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 1., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40., 100., 0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 50., 2.,0.))
        colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
        colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
        colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))
        colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
        colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
        colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))
        colorList.append((.67,.907,9,1.)) #12
        colorList.append((.1,.85,69.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,30.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,1.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((3.,0.,40.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.,.1,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 250., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((1.3,40.5,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((40.5,0.,35.5,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,2., 40.,0.))
        colorList.append((.3,40.,.1,0.))
        colorList.append((0.,40.5,.3,0.))
        colorList.append((35.5,40.,0.,0.))
        colorList.append((0., 0., 50.,0.))
        colorList.append((255.,105.,180.,0.))




        def makeMat(num):

            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = namez[i])
            mat.diffuse_color = colorList[i]
            mat.specular_color = (1., 1., 1.)
            return mat

      
        
        imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=faceObjectFile_path)


        for i in range(0, 47):
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius= r, location=noseLoop[i])
            sphere = bpy.context.object
            sphere.name = namez[i]
            mesh = sphere.data
            mat = makeMat(i)
            mesh.materials.append(mat)
            
            
            
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size= r, location=noseLoopNew[i])
            cube = bpy.context.object
            cube.name = (namezNew[i] + ' New')
            mesh = cube.data
            mat = makeMat(i)
            mesh.materials.append(mat)

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
         
        for i in range(0, 47):
            bpy.data.objects[namez[i]].select_set(True) # Blender 2.8x

        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = activeObj
        bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='VERTEX')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
        
        #insert mesh 1 (old nose mesh)
        # make mesh
        vertices = noseLoopNew
        edges = []
        faces = [[14,24,23],[14,24,22],[24,18,23],[24,17,22],[24,18,29],[24,29,17],[18,23,41],[17,22,40],[18,41,29],[29,17,40],[29,41,39],[29,40,39],[1,5,23],[5,41,23],[41,39,28],[39,40,28],[5,41,3],[3,41,7],[7,41,28],[28,40,6],[6,40,2],[22,2,4],[40,22,2],[22,4,0],[3,7,35],[7,35,28],[35,34,28],[28,34,6],[6,34,2],[34,2,26],[2,4,26],[4,31,26],[4,0,31],[32,1,5],[32,5,27],[5,27,3],[32,36,27],[3,27,35],[35,36,27],[34,35,36],[36,34,26],[36,26,31]]
        newNoseMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('newNoseMesh')
        newNoseMesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
        newNoseMesh.update()
        # make object from mesh
        newNoseMesh_object = bpy.data.objects.new('newNoseMesh_object', newNoseMesh)
        
        # create a collection
        mesh_collection = bpy.data.collections.new('mesh_collection')
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(mesh_collection)
        
        # add object to scene collection
        mesh_collection.objects.link(newNoseMesh_object)

        bpy.object = newNoseMesh
        newMeshMat = bpy.data.materials.new('New Mesh Mat')
        newMeshMat.use_nodes=True
        nodes = newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes
            
        newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.8, 0, 0.704733,1)
        newMeshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1

        newNoseMesh_object.active_material = newMeshMat
        newNoseMesh_object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
        
        #insert mesh 2
        vertices = noseLoop
        edges = []
        faces = [[14,24,23],[14,24,22],[24,18,23],[24,17,22],[24,18,29],[24,29,17],[18,23,41],[17,22,40],[18,41,29],[29,17,40],[29,41,39],[29,40,39],[1,5,23],[5,41,23],[41,39,28],[39,40,28],[5,41,3],[3,41,7],[7,41,28],[28,40,6],[6,40,2],[22,2,4],[40,22,2],[22,4,0],[3,7,35],[7,35,28],[35,34,28],[28,34,6],[6,34,2],[34,2,26],[2,4,26],[4,31,26],[4,0,31],[32,1,5],[32,5,27],[5,27,3],[32,36,27],[3,27,35],[35,36,27],[34,35,36],[36,34,26],[36,26,31]]
        oldNoseMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('oldNoseMesh')
        oldNoseMesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
        oldNoseMesh.update()
        # make object from mesh
        oldNoseMesh_object = bpy.data.objects.new('oldNoseMesh_object', oldNoseMesh)

        # add object to scene collection
        mesh_collection.objects.link(oldNoseMesh_object)

        bpy.object = oldNoseMesh
        meshMat = bpy.data.materials.new('Mesh Mat')
        meshMat.use_nodes=True
        nodes = meshMat.node_tree.nodes       

        meshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0.00205669, 0.8, 0.0157096, 1)
        meshMat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1 #.4  

        oldNoseMesh_object.active_material = meshMat

        oldNoseMesh_object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
        
        #change opcacity of face
        activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
        bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 0
        bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
        bpy.context.object.active_material.use_backface_culling = False
        

        #export face
        
        
        exportFileName = activeObj.name
        if "." in activeObj.name:
            print("Yes")
            exportFileName = exportFileName[:-4]
        
        #print(exportFileName)
        #export obj to face to (patientName)MeshNose.obj
        target_file = os.path.join(meshFile_path, exportFileName + ('MeshNose.obj'))

        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_file)
        
        #delete meshes
        bpy.data.objects['newNoseMesh_object'].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        bpy.data.objects['oldNoseMesh_object'].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        # solidify face
        activeObj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects[0]
        bpy.context.object.active_material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
        
        bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18].default_value = 1
        bpy.context.object.active_material.use_backface_culling = False
        
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
 
 
classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_dataPointsFile, 
            ADDONNAME_OT_newDataPointsFile, ADDONNAME_OT_faceObjectFile, ADDONNAME_OT_meshFile,
            ADDONNAME_OT_addPointsAndFace]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Hope this helps somebody!